# How to show the rank of the matrix $[a_1C_1| \cdots | a_nC_n]$ is equal to the rank of $[C_1| \cdots | C_n]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\Bbb F$ be a field. 
Suppose I have a matrix $[a_1C_1| \ldots | a_nC_n]$, where each $a_i \in\Bbb F$ and $C_i$ is a column vector in $\Bbb F^m$. 
Suppose $[a_1C_1| \ldots | a_nC_n]$ has full rank. 
I would like to show
$$
\operatorname{rank} ([a_1C_1| \cdots | a_nC_n]) =\operatorname{rank}([C_1|  \cdots | C_n]). 
$$ 
Any explanation of this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: No $a_i$ is zero because of the initial full rank assumption. But then it is clear that both collections of column vectors span the same sub space.

Comment: To refer to the previous comment, the fact the elementary column and row transformations don't change the rank is just a consequence of the already mentioned. One of those is scaling - obviously, scalar multiplication of the column vectors by $a_i\ne 0$.